# PHP : failed to open stream error when reading file name from file

Tags: php

I have a file input.txt that contains file names that I need to open and read data. I have written the following php code and I get the `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` when it tries to open with variable `$files`, i.e., the second fopen is failing.

```
$handle = fopen("/home/user/input.txt", "r");
if($handle) {
while(($files = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    print $files;
    $filename = fopen($files,"r");
    print $filename;
}
}
```

**input.txt content:**

```
/home/user/file_1
/home/user/file_2
/home/user/file_3
/home/user/file_4
```

`file_1`,`file_2`,`file_3` and `file_4` are in `/home/user/`
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: check permission of files and folders .... if php user is able to enter directory and read files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the file lines contains whitespaces (e.g. `\r`), to remove them we'll use `trim()`

```
function open_files_from_file_list()
{
 $handle = fopen("/home/user/input.txt", "r");
 if(!$handle)
   return;

 while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
 {
    $line=trim($line);
    print $line;
    if (!file_exists($line))
    {
       print ' does not exists';
       continue;
    }
    $filename = fopen($line,"r");
    print $filename;
 }
}
```